# How can I ensure that curl uses openssl, and not nss?

Tags: curl, fips, rhel6

Is it possible to ensure by a configuration [`parameter`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), that `curl` uses [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), and *not* [NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) to retrieve https content?  I need to ensure this, in order to enforce compliance with [FIPS140-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm), which RHEL6.2 has certified?

I think that answer is "no".

So I'll ask the follow-up here as well...  Can I recompile curl to ensure that it uses libssl and not libnss?  I've tried:

```
./configure --with-ssl --without-nss
```

and I still end up with a curl binary that dynamically links against `libnss3.so`.

```
[root@fips curl-7.19.7]# ldd /usr/bin/curl 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffacbe8000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f5d8fe03000)
        libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f5d8fbd1000)
        libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f5d8f983000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5d8f77b000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f5d8f537000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f5d8f250000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f5d8f024000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5d8ee20000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f5d8ebc2000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f5d8e828000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d8e624000)
        libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f5d8e3fb000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5d8e1e5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d8de52000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f5d8dc42000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5d8da28000)
        libssl3.so => /usr/lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007f5d8d7f2000)
        libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f5d8d5c5000)
--->    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f5d8d28a000)
--->    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f5d8d05f000)
        libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f5d8ce5a000)
        libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f5d8cc55000)
        libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f5d8ca18000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f5d8c7fd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5d8c5e0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5d90062000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f5d8c3d5000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f5d8c1d1000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f5d8bf99000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5d8bd7a000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f5d8bb18000)
```

Comment: is your recompiled curl really in /usr/bin/? some useful info is also e.g. [here](http://wiki.nikhef.nl/grid/Funny_Curly_things#Appendix:_building_curl)

Comment: @Dustin, How did you solve this issue.? I also need openSSL instead of NSS, but the server is configured with NSS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831667/change-curl-ssl-version

Comment: @Timo002, sadly, I have not solved it.  Recompiling curl was not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/include --without-nss
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. However if you go:
./configure --without-nss --with-ssl=/usr/lib64
it picks up the openssl library correctly and excludes nss. Some parts of libcurl will use nss (I don't know what) so ldd will report it linking with nss but that was not the problem in my case. I checked the install directory in /usr/lib64 and it still had the old libcurl library there. My copy was installed into /usr/lib/local/. So when I removed the ones in /usr/lib64 and replaced them with all the newly generated files it worked. SO I guess you could configure with --libdir=/usr/lib64 but you must remove the old libraries. Then I did ldconfig to reload them.