# Change curl SSL Version

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I'm using SOAP to communicate with a webservice. I had this running on a buggy server but it was running fine. Now I'm running this on a better server but with different configurations.

At the new server I'm getting authentification errors, I think the problem is the SSL Version of curl. Somewhere I thought that should be OpenSSL. Doing a `phpinfo()` on both servers gives me a difference.

Working server: `SSL Version    OpenSSL/0.9.8b`.

Not working server: `SSL Version    NSS/3.13.1.0`

Server is a VPS with CentOS v6 and Parallels Plesk Panel 11.5

**EDIT**

The webservice requires NTLM authentication and therefore I'm using this class, that was working fine at the old server. http://tcsoftware.net/blog/2011/08/php-soapclient-authentication/

Comment: What authentication errors are you getting?

Comment: 401 error: Complete error `Error Code: 401 Unauthorized. The server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web server is denied. Contact the server administrator. (12209).`

Comment: I had a similar issue with PHP curl, but I was getting this error back: "SSL connect error." To fix that one (maybe it helps you too) I set this curl option: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "rsa_rc4_128_sha");`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue, but it had nothing to do with cURL SSL version.

I had to change the cURL setting `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` from `CURLAUTH_ANY` to `CURLAUTH_NTLM`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
```

Which is a little strange because according https://www.php.net/curl_setopt `CURLAUTH_ANY` stands for:

```
CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST | CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM
```